# Using imported modules with "Pandas on Spark" Pyspark feature

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working off an enterprise data platform (databricks-like) where I have a Jupyter notebook environment that can allow me to run pyspark code on the driver node. Utilising the "Spark on Pandas" feature from Spark 3.2 and above (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html), I can run the following pseudo code where I define my function in the notebook.

```py
def foo():
    ...

import pyspark.pandas as ps

pyspark_df = spark.read.parquet("...")
psdf = pyspark_df.to_pandas_on_spark()
psdf.apply(lambda row: foo(row))
```

However, if my function was defined in a separate Python module that was imported into my notebook. I now run into ModuleNotFound errors on the executor nodes.

```py
# Doesn't work

from bar import foo
import pyspark.pandas as ps

pyspark_df = spark.read.parquet("...")
psdf = pyspark_df.to_pandas_on_spark()
psdf.apply(lambda row: foo(row))
```

If I were running a spark-submit I could specify the additional python dependencies, but how can I do the equivalent while in a notebook environment?

Wonder if there is a "Pandas on Spark" expert who can chime in on the simplest approach to solve this?

Comment: I think you know the answer here. The custom module needs to be installed on the workers. For Databricks, you'd package the wheel and upload it to be installed. So you need to figure out how to get that installed on the enterprise platform. If your Spark uses Kubernetes Spark, it needs to be baked into the image, which is a bit painful for iteration.

Comment: Thank you @KevinKho, that is indeed the unfortunate answer I've arrived at as well. Oh well, glad to know there wasn't a simpler workaround.